# router.get doesn't work but router.get with id works

Tags: javascript, express, web-applications, routes

calling http://localhost:5000/surveycreate/4 works and redirects me to 
surveypage.html

but calling http://localhost:5000/surveycreate does not work, it redirects me my my main index.js file in public folder it doesn't even print "regular get"

why is this happening?

surveypage.js in route

````
const path = require("path");
const router = express.Router();

router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));

router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {

  console.log("get with id");
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/Surveypage.html"));

})

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {

  console.log("regular get");
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/Surveypage.html"));

})


module.exports = router; ```
==============================================================================
index.js of node:

const surveyPage = require('./routes/surveypage')

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/surveypage',surveyPage)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));
app.use(cors())
const PORT  = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(PORT , () => {
    console.log(`Listenning on porst ${PORT }`);

})
````

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the structure of your files correspond with your code.

The following code is working well for me:

**app.js:**

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors")
const surveyPage = require('./routes/surveypage')
const path = require("path");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/surveypage', surveyPage)
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public"))); // not needed
app.use(cors())


app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listenning on porst ${PORT }`))
```

**surveypage.js**

```js
const path = require("path");
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();

router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/Surveypage.html")));
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/Surveypage.html")))

module.exports = router;
```